# Is it possible to save a channel permissions in the database?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, permissions, discord.js

So I created a "Join to Create" system that creates a voice when a user joins and delete it when they leave. I also created commands that allow them to change channel permissions.

I was wondering if it's possible to save their permissions in the database so when they create another channel, it creates with that same perms. So far I could only do that with channel name.

```
await channel.overwritePermissions([
    {
      id: user.id,
      allow: ["MANAGE_CHANNELS", "CONNECT"],
    },
    {
      id: member.guild.id,
      deny: ["CONNECT"],
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: So how did you do it with the name...?